# Xamarin Refresh Collection from ViewModel from another class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

what is the best method to add/remove objects to a ObservableCollection in a ViewModel from another class in Xamarin.Forms?

Lets say I have a collection from type "Thing". The Thing model contains name and description as a string.

Now I want to add a "Thing" object from another Page to this collection.

What is a way to do it?

Comment: please avoid asking for "best" or "better", those are matters of opinion.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  You could pass the entire ObservableCollection to the 2nd page.  You could create the new object on the first page and pass it to the 2nd page to populate the values.  You could use MessagingCenter to pass a message from the 2nd page to the 1st when the object is added.

Comment: Hi @Jason, thanks for your input. I tried to pass the entire Collection to the 2nd page but could not get it work with Xamarin Shell and QueryProperties.

Comment: if you are using Shell that will not work.  I'd try MessagingCenter

Comment: Create a template xamarin.forms solution, which shows one way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter class implements the publish-subscribe pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references.
You can use MessagingCenter.Send to send object to the page and use MessagingCenter.Subscribe to receive it.
Here is how I do in the new sample shell app:

DisplayPage:

```
     public partial class DisplayPage : ContentPage
        {
            public static ObservableCollection<People> mycol = new ObservableCollection<People>();
            public DisplayPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                People p1 = new People("Adam", 20);
                People p2 = new People("Bob", 22);
                People p3 = new People("Candy", 39);
                mycol.Add(p1);
                mycol.Add(p2);
                mycol.Add(p3);
                //recieve message
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<OperatePage, People>(this, "message",  (sender, arg) =>
                {
                    mycol.Add(arg);
                });
                col.ItemsSource = mycol;
    
            }
        }
```

SendObject:

```
  protected void onButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = inputname.Text;
            int age = Int16.Parse(inputage.Text);
            People newguy = new People(name,age);
            MessagingCenter.Send<OperatePage, People>(this, "message", newguy);
```

Results:

[image][image][image]